# Sum a sequence of integers in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, sequences

I have the function `bool exists(int sum, vector<int>& vec)`
What it does is to return whether there is any sequence of numbers in `vec` that equals `sum`.

e.g

`Vec = 140 80 90 180 70`
`sum = 300`

The function returns `true` because the sequence `140 90 70` exists and equals 300.

For now i have the code:

```
bool possible(int sum, vector<int> &vec)
{
do
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        s += vec.at(i);
        if (s == sum)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}while(next_permutation(vec.begin(), vec.end()));

return false;
}
```

It works but takes too long even when the vector size is just 20.

Can anyone help me with a better approach?

Comment: This problem is as hard as [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: As I see the task requires about N! iterations. 20! is 2,43*10^18, and it can't be faster in a general.

Comment: Maybe this can help. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem

Comment: Can you sort the numbers?

Comment: I've rolled back the question because you changed the code to a different algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It works

First, it does not quite work, unless `vec` is sorted to begin with. Otherwise, `next_permutation(...)` would produce `false` without exhausting all possibilities, possibly skipping the permutation in which the right solution would be found.

> but takes too long even when the vector size is just 20.

That's because this is an O(N!) solution. Note that `N!` is unnecessarily high even for a brute force solution, because the order in which you do additions does not matter. All you need is O(2<sup>N</sup>) to try all subsets.

You can do better by employing a pseudo-polynomial solution to [0/1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem). The idea is to create a set of all possible sums up to the desired number N. Start the set with a single number, zero. The on each iteration produce another set with contains all elements of the set from the previous iteration, plus the set produced by adding a number from your list to each of the previous sums, limiting the values at your target number (i.e. 300):

```
{ 0 }
{ 0, 140 } -- Added 0+140
{ 0, 80, 140, 220 } -- Added 0+80, 140+80
{ 0, 80, 90, 140, 170, 220, 230 } -- Added 0+90, 80+90, 140+90; 220+90 > 300, so it is not added
... // And so on
```

At the end of this process you would have all possible sums in the set. Now all you need to do is to check if your target number is present among the items in the set.

Comment: @jafar Your implementation from the edit uses `binary_search` to look for a number in a non-ordered container. Either sort the vector, or use linear search.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool possible(int sum, vector<int> &vec)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
      s += vec.at(i);
    }

    if (s==sum)
    return true;
    else
    return false;

}
```

This would be more efficient, just adding the vector values together and comparing the results at the end. In this case you wouldn't do any permutation calculations and you wouldn't need to have a for loop inside a do... while loop either.

Comment: You are using the wrong data type for your index counter `i`. It should be a `size_type` instead of an `int`. Using an iterator is recommended: `for ( auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it ) s += *it;` This also avoids the costly `at`-calls.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working code.

```
bool possible(int sum, vector<int &vec)
{
    vector<int> previous;
    previous.push_back(0);

    for(auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++)
    {
        vector<int> temp(previous);
        for(auto j = temp.begin();  j != temp.end(); j++)
            *j += *i;
        for(auto k = temp.begin(); k != temp.end(); k++)
        {
            if(*k <= sum)
                previous.push_back(*k);
        }
    }
    sort(previous.begin(),previous.end());
    return binary_search(previous.begin(),previous.end(),sum);
}
```

Thanks guys.